# Java Condition fail to re-aquire the lock(a ReentrantLock) associated with it after await() returns

Tags: java, locking, conditional-statements

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Foo {
    private ReentrantLock _lock;
    private Condition _cond;
    private Thread _thr;
    private LinkedList<String> _msgQueue;

    public Foo() {
        _lock = new ReentrantLock();
        _cond = _lock.newCondition();
        _msgQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
        startThread();
    }

    public void putMsg(String msg) throws Exception {
        _lock.lock();
        _msgQueue.addLast(msg);
        _cond.signal();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": Signal write thread.");
        _lock.unlock();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": Unlocked.");
    }

    private void startThread() {
        _thr = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                _lock.lock();
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        while (!_msgQueue.isEmpty()) {
                            String msg = _msgQueue.getFirst();
                            System.out.println(msg);
                            _msgQueue.removeFirst();
                        }

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": getHoldCount:" + _lock.getHoldCount());
                        System.out.println((Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": isLocked:" + _lock.isLocked()));
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": isHeldByCurrentThread:" + _lock.isHeldByCurrentThread());
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": Awaiting...");

                        _cond.await();

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": Write thread awaken");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            _lock.unlock();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Write thread exit.");
            }
        };

        _thr.start();
    }
}

public class LockTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.putMsg("Msg 1");
        foo.putMsg("Msg 2");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        foo.putMsg("Msg 3");
    }
}
```

```
The code output after one running:
1: Signal write thread.
1: Unlocked.
1: Signal write thread.
1: Unlocked.
Msg 1
Msg 2
8: getHoldCount:1
8: isLocked:true
8: isHeldByCurrentThread:true
8: Awaiting...
1: Signal write thread.
1: Unlocked.
8: Write thread awaken
Msg 3
8: getHoldCount:0
8: isLocked:false
8: isHeldByCurrentThread:false
8: Awaiting...
Write thread exit.
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException at

java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(Unknown Source) at

java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(Unknown Source) at 

java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.fullyRelease(Unknown Source) at 

java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source) 

at Foo$1.run(LockTest.java:44)
```

The question is:
According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await(), when the thread returns it is guaranteed to hold this lock. But from the output, we see that after await() returns, it does not re-aquire the lock. Is this a bug or are some mistakes I made?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I'm trying to post my code, the editor *Markdown* code checking always refuses my post...

Comment: Finally, the code comes...

Answer (score 1):

> According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await(), when the thread returns it is guaranteed to hold this lock.

True, but it also says that the thread must hold the lock before calling the method:

> The current thread is assumed to hold the lock associated with this Condition when this method is called. It is up to the implementation to determine if this is the case and if not, how to respond. Typically, an exception will be thrown (such as IllegalMonitorStateException) and the implementation must document that fact.

This works the same way as a "normal" monitor (Object#wait): You have to hold the lock when you start waiting (with a synchronized block in the case of Object#wait, with Lock#lock here). The lock will then be released and you wait. When the wait is over, you also hold the lock again.

Comment: Yes, I did hold the lock before await(), you can see _lock.lock() which is the first statement in the run() method. I put the lock() into while(true), the code runs correctly, but do I have to do this? Need lock() everytime after await() returns?

Comment: You need to lock() everytime you want to await(). You can probably just keep the lock() once on top, but right now, you have a finally unlock() for every iteration.